# Add shp. name as attribute, looping through dates

Tags: date, attributes

I have been stuck on this for a few days.  I have a folder with hundreds of shapefiles.  I want to add an attribute field to the shapefiles giving the shapefile's name as a date.  The shapefile name includes Landsat path/row, year, and Julien date ('1800742003032.shp).  I want just the date '2003032' to be added under a "Date" field.

Here's what I have so far:

arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Users\mkelly\Documents\Namibia\Raster_Water\1993\Polygons" 
for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*", "ALL"): 
    print str("processing" +  fc) 
    field = "DATE" 
    expression = str(fc)[6:13] 
    arcpy.AddField_management(fc, field, "TEXT") 
    arcpy.CalculateField_management(fc, field, "expression", "PYTHON")

Results:

processing1800742003032.shp 
processing1800742009136.shp 
processing1820732010289.shp 
end Processing...

It runs perfectly (on a sample 3 shapefiles) but the problem is that when I open the shapefiles in Arcmap, they all have the same date.  The results show that it processed each of the 3 shapefiles, and the add field management must have worked because all of the fields are populated.  So there is an issue with either the expression, or the Calculate field command.

How can I get it to populate the specific date for each shapefile, and not just have all of them be '2003032'?? There are no error messages.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: PS: I tried the File Name Insert script by Rocky Rudolph multiple times and couldn't get it to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! For calculate field management, expression should not be in quotes. It should be: arcpy.CalculateField_management(fc, field, expression, "PYTHON")

This post may have been a waste of time, but at least maybe it will help someone with a similar problem in the future.